# Enforce app store update

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a feature in the app that when I have pushed a new version of my app to the app store, I notify the user and redirect him directly to the app store. However, in this app store, many users see a cached version. Their app store is not up-to-date. I read [here](http://lifehacker.com/force-refresh-the-ios-app-store-by-tapping-the-tab-bar-1750465871) how they can update the app store, after which they see the new version. I don't want to explain this trick however to all my users. Is there another link I can use to always send them to the most up-to-date version? Is there another way for me to make sure the users use the latest version of the app?

p.s. It's passed review, it's live and users are in the correct region.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with supercell games like Clash of Clans, Boom Beach, etc. they force users to go to the App Store to download the latest version of the app.

The way that they do this is to retrieve the latest version of the app from their servers.  If you have a server, you can store the latest version of your app in a database and read that value on the start of your app.  If it does not match then redirect users to the App Store.

Here is a SO link for sending users to the App Store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/3543861

Just make sure to replace the iTunesLink with your app's url.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am using right now. Unfortunately, the users see an old version of the app in the App store.

Comment: Yeah, I also face the App Store problem. Unfortunately I usually have to wait about 24 hours for the version to be updated in every App Store, but I've never experienced this problem for more than 24 hours

Comment: I guess it's waiting and monitoring then. Thanks anyway!