# How to open app store in ios app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code to rate app from an ios application.

```
let appLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[name of the app]/id[idnumber]?mt=8"
let url = URL(string: appLink)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

the problem is Safari says "the page address is invalid"

Is there any way to make it work? I'm using xcode 9 and swift 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your URL can simply be:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id<App ID Here>?mt=8
```

Better yet, use `SKStoreProductViewController` so you can show the app in an App Store page without the need to leave your app.

And as of iOS 10.3 you can `SKStoreReviewController` specifically to allow a user to post a review or rate an app.

Comment: thanks! I solved my probles using SKStoreProductViewController

Answer (score 1):

Use the **STORE KIT** request review based on the new guidelines and documentation found here.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

On older version you can use

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=<AppId>&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software
```