# SKStoreProductViewController().loadProduct() does not work in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, storekit

Since 2 days I've a got this problem.
In my app I want to display the SKStoreProductViewController() for my cross promotion. In my Iphone 7 the loadProduct() function reach the completion block but in my iPad it never reach it. So I'm not able to dispay the StoreProductView on my iPad.
I try to set the identifier as Int and as String, but it's the same problem. No one works.
In both device I have the same itunes account connected.

I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: please...if you not resolve this, go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store/47415150#47415150 .  Maybe is your solution