# Create iOS app store links for social media and messaging? Error: Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) is similar but doesn't address how to create links that can be shared and opened via iMessage, email, or social media.

[The Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html) suggests URLs of the format `http://appstore.com/companyname` (e.g., `http://appstore.com/gameloft`) if the goal is to list all apps by a company.

However, opening links like this generate an error in Safari, specifically that

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

1) What iOS App Store URL format will display all the apps from a company, and works from both mobile iOS and desktop?

2) What iOS App Store URL format will display a single app, and works from both mobile iOS and desktop?

Comment: 1) Try `https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/[company-name]/id[company-id]`. 2) Try `https://itunes.apple.com/app/id[app-id]`. Can't promise those will work on mobile, but they certainly work on desktop :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for creating links to iTunes content is to use the iTunes Link Maker, https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/.

You can select your country and the content type, e.g. app, music, etc, and search for the content you want, and then you will recieve valid links for different purposes...

But you can generate only links to content, not to a company

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not testing on the OS Simulator because it doesn't come with an app store, so your links will return invalid. Instead, try testing the links on an actual iOS device.