# Opening a url is failing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

breakpointing inside the callback and logging success shows false.

I added itms-apps to my plist: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

and put this in my app delegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func moreTapped() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.com/developer/quantum-productions/id979315877")
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: {(success: Bool) in

        })
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: I try on a device, get "Cannot Connect to App Store". Device is online

Comment: You don't call `canOpenURL(_:)` first? Do you have any log message?

Comment: Follow this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: Try URL as itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quantum-productions/id979315877

Comment: @Shoaib this shows "Item not available"

Comment: Are the app that you want to open published on app store.

Comment: It's NOT an app. It's a developer page.

Comment: Try with `URL()` instead of `NSURL()` and use a `guard` statement with `canOpenURL(_:)`  for early exit before even going to `UIApplication.shared.open()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the incorrect format for your URL, and you should use `URL` rather than `NSURL` in Swift.

This will open your developer page in the App Store app:

```
if let url = URL(string:"itms-apps://geo.itunes.apple.com/developer/quantum-productions/id979315877&mt=8") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

There is no need to call `canOpenURL` for standard URL types such as `http/s` and `itms`.

Comment: Are you sure the scheme isn't `itms-apps`? I just tried it on mobile safari and at least from there I am not asked to open it in the AppStore app, but with itms-app I am. The domain correction etc you propose (using `geo`) seems correct.

Comment: Boinks, you edited right as I saved. Kudos, the answer is correct. :)

Comment: Itms also kind of works, but it opens the iTunes Store instead of the App Store, which isn't what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple just announced the appstore.com URLs.**

**

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

**

> **To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:**
>
> Remove all whitespace
>
> Convert all characters to lower-case
>
> Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®)
>   symbols
>
> Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
>
> Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
>
> Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with
>   their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
>
> Leave all other characters as-is.
>
> Listing 2 Punctuation characters that must be removed.
>
> !¡"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>¿?@[]^_`{|}~
>
> Below are some examples to demonstrate the conversion that takes
>   place.
>
> **App Name examples**
>
> **Ocarina =>** http://appstore.com/ocarina

According to Apple's latest document **items-apps:** or items: won't not work. You need to use

> appStoreLink =
>   "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8"
>
> or
>
> **> SKStoreProductViewController**

Comment: Example: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class