# Redirection from html page to itunes in InAppBrowser in ios cordova

Tags: html, ios, cordova, redirect, inappbrowser

We are not able to redirect from one html page to itunes from InAppBrowser in ios cordova.
We are using following logic for redirection from html page to itunes :

```
1) window.open("itunes url","_system");
2) window.open("itunes url","_blank");
3) window.location = "itunes url";
```

We are able to navigate to play store in android using window.location.
Please suggest appropriate solution for this issue.

PS : The itunes url is having location of our app on app store.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store