# Is there any way open installed mobile app (iTunes store) on IOS Safari?

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, itunes

is it possible from link in IOS Safari open installed **iTunes Store** app?

Googled and founded 'universal links' but don't reilise how it works with default apple apps.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to make a link that opens up the iTunes Store where a user can then choose to install the app?

Comment: Yes it works but it would be much better directly open iTunes Store app without opening AppStore

Comment: have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store yet

Comment: <a href="itms://apps.apple.com/by/app/itunes-store">test</a> works but open 'item not available' - how can I navigate to music/video folder inside iTunes Store?

Comment: did you change to href to match your app