# Is it possible to download another app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m new to swift, and was wondering if I could download an iPhone/iPad app using swift (for example, I’m looking for something like an App Store API).

Comment: You can link to an app and the user can download it. You cannot download it directly using an app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: And it depends upon your intent. I.e., if your intent is to offer a store-like experience for downloading apps, see [section 3.2.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable) of the App Store Guidelines, which considers the following as unacceptable: “Creating an interface for displaying third-party apps, extensions, or plug-ins similar to the App Store or as a general-interest collection.”

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

Apple's security protections don't allow apps to install other apps. That would be a huge vulnerability.

And, as Rob pointed out in his comment, creating your own App Store would be a direct violation of the App Store guidelines you have to agree to in order to publish your apps on Apple's App Store. (Their ball, their rules.)