# How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to have a feature in my app where the user can send an email to a friend with the iTunes URL to my application. How is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Rather than the long and confusing urls that you usually see, you can create App Store links that are much simpler and more logical. The iTunes Store has a hidden URL format that’s much more logical. Depending on what you’re linking to, you just need to build a URL in one of these formats:

1. Artist’s name or App Store developer’s name: http://itunes.com/Artist_Or_Developer_Name
2. Album name: http://itunes.com/Artist_Name/Album_Name
3. Apps: http://itunes.com/app/App_Name
4. Movies: http://itunes.com/movie/Movie_Title
5. TV: http://itunes.com/tv/Show_Title

Just include a url of this format in the body of the email you create.

(Note that spaces might cause problems, but I found that omitting them entirely worked for me - http://itunes.com/app/FrootGroove redirects to the app called "Froot Groove".)

(Also note that if this doesn't work for you, the iTunes link maker is [here](http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsLinkMaker))

Your code will be something like this (extracted from mine, anonymised and not tested)

```
NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Get my app here - %@.\n",myUrl];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED <= __IPHONE_2_2
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
NSString* crlfBody = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\r\n"];
NSString* escapedBody = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,  (CFStringRef)crlfBody, NULL,  CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];

NSString *mailtoPrefix = [@"mailto:xxx@wibble.com?subject=Get my app&body=" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Finally, combine to create the fully escaped URL string
NSString *mailtoStr = [mailtoPrefix stringByAppendingString:escapedBody];

// And let the application open the merged URL
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailtoStr]];
#endif
```

You can do better things in iPhone 3.0, but I can't talk about those yet.

Comment: Wow i had no idea you could do this.  Thanks for this post!

Comment: One quick question - if my app display name (in info.plist) and iTunes name (as specified in iTunes Connect) are different, which one should I use in the URL? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not certain, but suspect the iTunes name.

Comment: so what are the new things in OS 3.0?

Comment: This does work, but it seems to redirect to a search. If you are the only match for that search, then you are golden. If not, sadly not.

Comment: That link maker reference is the way to go. Google Play has a similar page at https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/badges.html

Answer (score 4):

In OS 3.0 you can use the MessageUI framework to do this without leaving the app (using Jane's code as the fallback for pre-3.0 devices):

```
- (void)sendEmail
{
    NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Get my app here - %@.\n",myUrl];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED <= __IPHONE_2_2
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil && [mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        picker.subject = @"Get my app";
        [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxx@wibble.com"];
        [picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
        [picker release];
    } else {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
        NSString* crlfBody = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\r\n"];
        NSString* escapedBody = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,  (CFStringRef)crlfBody, NULL,  CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];

        NSString *mailtoPrefix = [@"mailto:xxx@wibble.com?subject=Get my app&body=" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        // Finally, combine to create the fully escaped URL string
        NSString *mailtoStr = [mailtoPrefix stringByAppendingString:escapedBody];

        // And let the application open the merged URL
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailtoStr]];
    }
#endif
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Mail Composer Delegate
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription] message:[error localizedFailureReason] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK") otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note that your class must adopt the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol. You can also include attachments, use HTML in the body, and more.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use appstore.com/APP_NAME to launch an app in iTunes. This works on the desktop and on iOS devices. This is not as reliable as other methods however. See answer here [How to create vanity url for apple appStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687635/how-to-create-vanity-url-for-apple-appstore)

Answer (score 1):

This code **generates the app store link automatically** based on the app name, nothing else is required, **drag & drop**:

```
NSCharacterSet *trimSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet];    
NSArray *trimmedAppname = [[NSString stringWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:trimSet];
NSString *appStoreLink = @"http://itunes.com/app/"; 
for (NSString *part in trimmedAppname) appStoreLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",appStoreLink,part];
NSLog(@"App store URL:%@",appStoreLink);
```

It gives you a link like http://itunes.com/app/angrybirds

Comment: You cannot do just this. Apple also replaces all special characters (like apostrophes, commas, ampersand etc) with a hyphen

Comment: Good point, I don't have any of those only space. But for most the URL can be extracted from the App name without knowing the app id or anything else. I will update the code when I have a chance. This one should work for most but not for all.

Comment: I updated the code, it should filter out all non-alaphanumerical characters. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the link to the application by its ID can be found by visiting the Apps Store for your application and clicking on the "Tell A Friend" -- then send an email to yourself.  I found this to be very informative.

Comment: Or just right-click the app name in iTunes (desktop app) and do a Copy link. That gives you the link as well :)