# Add url link or image(with url link) to mail app - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:?subject=Wallpapers%203d%20App&body=Have%20fun%20with%20this%20unique%20wallpaper%20app"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

I am using this code to open the mail app at iphone in order the user to send an email.
I want to add a url link or image(with url linke) inside the mail which the user sends so when his friend opens his email and taps to the link he will be redirected to the app store and download the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `MFMailComposeViewController` instead of `mailto:` links to send mails. This gives you more control, e.g. you can attach an image with it.
2. See [How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818973/iphone-how-can-i-include-a-url-to-my-app-in-the-app) about how to get the URL to your app.