# Open iTunes from an iPad app to a specific app (advertise my own apps inside my own apps)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xamarin.ios, itunes

When a user clicks the "SHow me more" button in my app, I want to open iTunes on the iPad to that app so they can buy it too.

How is this done in Objective-C (or Monotouch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just openURL to your user id, for instance, mine is `http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/wrightscs/id387614647`

You can goto one of your apps in iTunes, click on your name and all of your apps will come up, right-click on your name and copy the link.

```
    NSString *urlText = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/vendor/id000000";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow WrightCS's url convention to construct your own url, and then use this line of code to open it. Don't worry, iOS is smart enough to open the iTunes app for you.

```
//aUrl is a NSURL instance    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:aUrl];
```

For a complete list on how to construct those urls, check this great post: [How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818973/iphone-how-can-i-include-a-url-to-my-app-in-the-app)