# How to link to iTunes page of my app from within the very same app even before I submit the app to the store?

Tags: iphone

I am having an app. I am going to submit it to the store. In that app I am having a button that should go to iTunes page of the very same app. I guess there should be a way to do that using app bundle or plist or something..

1. If I can do it, How I can do it?
2. Is it possible to get the link of an app in itunes store even before it is submitted to the store?

Thank you..

Comment: Apple won't allow your app, because a feature isn't working. :)

Comment: @Time Machine: Because which feature isn't working?

Comment: the link to the app store isn't yet working, as your app isn't yet in the app store during the first review. You need to upload the first version without the button, and when it's available, you can upload a second version with the button.

Comment: @Time Machine: Hmm this makes sense.. Thanks.. But @taskinoor's answer seems to be a proper way of doing it. Isn't it?

Comment: @Time Machine: I don't have any prior experience in this regard. That's why I am asking your suggestion..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iTunes store URL is something like this.

http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=your_app_id&mt=8

You can get the your_app_id after creating the app in iTunes. That means you just need to create the app to get the URL. No need to submit the app just to get the ID.

After getting the ID, open that URL from the button handler.

Comment: @taskinoor: Is it that simple?

Comment: @taskinoor: This is the first time I am submitting an app to the store. Can you please tell me, what is the link to create an app in the store?

Comment: I did this more than one time. It is that simple.

Comment: @taskinoor: Can you please tell me, what is the link to create an app in the store?

Comment: You need to login in your developer account and create through iTunes connect. There is a detail guide on how to create the app, submit that etc. etc. Be very careful with the publisher/company name. Once created you cannot change that in future. All of your apps will share the common publisher name.

Answer (score 5):

http://itunes.com/apps/myappname

Where "myappname" is your app name minus spaces and all lowercase.

Working examples:

- http://itunes.com/apps/amazon
- http://itunes.com/apps/thevoid
- http://itunes.com/apps/huluplus

Answer (score 1):

You could use the easy-to-read link feature as outlined in this [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1633.html). Just be aware that this link takes a few minutes to become active after your application has changed state to "Available For Sale".

Answer (score 1):

I answered this two years ago, here: [How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818973/iphone-how-can-i-include-a-url-to-my-app-in-the-app/819064#819064)