# Open iTunes from iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I need to open iTunes app store from my application. I used the following link. But the error is:

> Your Request Could Not Be Completed

My code is as below:

```
NSString *referralLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/esperanza/id321585893";
NSURL *iTunesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:referralLink];
NSURLRequest *referralRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:iTunesURL];
NSURLConnection *referralConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:referralRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[referralConnection release];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:iTunesURL];
```

Comment: There is a classic post on this topic on SO, you can't miss it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818973/iphone-how-can-i-include-a-url-to-my-app-in-the-app

Answer (score 3):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/album/esperanza/id321585893"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Not http://

Comment: Sorry, It also not Working..  
The same error showing... "Your Request Could Not Be Completed". –

Comment: remove the /us/ to become:
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/album/esperanza/id321585893

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSURL *appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/esperanza/id321585893"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreUrl];
```

Comment: The same error showing...  "Your Request Could Not Be Completed".

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/album/esperanza/id321585893"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But it is looking like, the Esperanza Album is available for USA and few specif countries.

If it is not available for your country, it will show the error message **"Your request could not be completed"**.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone support phobos link to open itunes url

Use this link

```
NSURL *appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=321585893&amp;amp;amp;amp;mt=8"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreUrl];
```

It will not work on iOS simulator.It will only work on iPhone.