# iTunes link cannot be opened in UI web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

I'm using iTunes link maker to access an album on iTunes.

Somehow the link doesn't open in UIWebView.

Anyone experienced this?

Is this a restriction or something? An update maybe?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/linkin-park/id148662?uo=4 
Please try this url and tell me if you experienced the same thing.

Comment: Do other links work for you? If yes, please post your code.

Comment: Are you using a simulator ? It'll show "Cannot open this it seems invalid" because iTunes is not installed in the simulator, and it is preferred you open it as a `NSURL` and check in device. Simulator will show an error.

Comment: Gosh! I was trolled by the simulator, thanks chief!

Comment: Haha i've faced this before :D. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any link that have "`itunes.apple.com`" will not work on the Simulator.

Thanks @iNoob!

Comment: Glad to help! :D, you can accept your own answer by the way. Just hit the check mark next to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this:

[How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818973/1439815)

Also in the Apple Developer documentation read this: Launching the App Store from an iPhone application (you'll have to find it, I can't share a link to a secure site here).