# How to create vanity url for apple appStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, vanity-url

Recently news are coming out that one can create vanity url for Apple Appstore.
[image]

But I cant find any options additionally added in itunes connect to do it.

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems we dont have to do anything ...
just we have to add the company name or app name at the end of http://appstore.com/

It seems since all the app names and company names are already unique, apple does the all background job of rerouting the appstore-link to the actual itunes-link..

iOS: http://appstore.com/<.companyname.> for example, http://appstore.com/ikural

Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/<.companyname.> for example, http://appstore.com/mac/popcap

apple has provided this [Q&A page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't create it. It is based on your company or application name. It is not very robust (two applications with the same name can have the same URL). See Apple's [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html).
In particular, the last paragraph reads:

> These App Store Short Links are provided as a convenience and are not
>   guaranteed to link to a particular app or company. Be sure to test
>   your URLs before using them in any marketing or other public
>   materials. If there are naming conflicts, continue using the standard
>   itunes.apple.com URLs, which contain a unique numerical identifier
>   within the URL.

Comment: I think applications names are unique, there are no two applications with same name. I think so ..

Comment: Despite the fact that names are unique my short appstore url http://appstore.com/StepTracker doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?