# Rating the Application in iphone

Tags: iphone, rating-system

i am trying to build a ratings alert inside my iPhone application which I want to make it look similar to the alert view, when the application is going to be delete.But i would like to make the rating by pressing the button it should send my rating to the itunes. is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Please rephrase and try again.

Comment: Actually I need to prompt the Voting Popup within my App by clicking a button. The user has to set the Stars in the popup  and submit it by clicking the "Vote" button in the popup which intern ( in background) update the rating of my app  in the Appstore/ itunes. Here we allow the user to give his rate/vote without closing the app. This is the requirement. Please give your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programatically insert reviews into the App Store. The best you can do is ask users to give a review, then open up a URL linking to your app in the App Store. See here for more information: [How Can I Launch The Appstore App Directly from my Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226986/how-can-i-launch-the-appstore-app-directly-from-my-application)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please press the ✔ next to it.