# iphone app store redirects

Tags: iphone, button, redirect

I have a button on a page that I am sending iphone users to.  This button is linked to the app on the app store.  The problem is that when an iphone user lands on this page, it is automatically going to apple.com and the person is not seeing the page and not able to click on the button.  The client does not want this.

These are the links I have been using:

http://itunes.com/apps/kibits

itms://itunes.com/apps/kibits

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kibits/id477515854?ls=1&mt=8

All of them are doing the same thing.  Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226986/how-can-i-launch-the-appstore-app-directly-from-my-application

try this

Answer (score 1):

Its sound like the problem is **not** with the **links**, but with the page the users are landing on. Thats where you need to look. The links are working fine I just tested them.